# Elasticsearch with 2 replicas stuck on ContainerCreating on EKS 1.24+

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kubernetes, upgrade, amazon-eks

While upgrading one of our EKS dev envs to version 1.24 i encountered an issue on in our ES sts, its stuck on ContainerCreating without any events/logs..

I checked and it seems to only be an issue when having 2 replicas of ES as a cluster, any idea what may be the cause of this?

Describe of pod:

```
Name:                 elasticsearch-0
Namespace:            XXXXXXXXXXX
Priority:             2000000
Priority Class Name:  apps
Service Account:      es
Node:                 XXXXXXXXXXX
Start Time:           Fri, 30 Jun 2023 04:17:55 +0300
Labels:               app=elasticsearch
                      controller-revision-hash=elasticsearch-68574b48b5
                      owner=control-plane
                      statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=elasticsearch-0
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Pending
IP:                   
IPs:                  <none>
Controlled By:        StatefulSet/elasticsearch
Containers:
  elastic:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          es:7.17.5
    Image ID:       
    Ports:          9200/TCP, 9300/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     4
      memory:  8Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      500m
      memory:   4Gi
    Readiness:  exec [bash -c set -e
# If the node is starting up wait for the cluster to be ready (request params: "wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s" )
# Once it has started only check that the node itself is responding
START_FILE=/tmp/.es_start_file

# Disable nss cache to avoid filling dentry cache when calling curl
# This is required with Elasticsearch Docker using nss < 3.52
export NSS_SDB_USE_CACHE=no

http () {
  local path="${1}"
  local args="${2}"
  set -- -XGET -s

  if [ "$args" != "" ]; then
    set -- "$@" $args
  fi

  if [ -n "${ES_PASS}" ]; then
    set -- "$@" -u "${ES_USER}:${ES_PASS}"
  fi

  curl --output /dev/null -k "$@" "http://127.0.0.1:9200${path}"
}

if [ -f "${START_FILE}" ]; then
  echo 'Elasticsearch is already running, lets check the node is healthy'
  HTTP_CODE=$(http "/" "-w %{http_code}")
  RC=$?
  if [[ ${RC} -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "curl --output /dev/null -k -XGET -s -w '%{http_code}' \${BASIC_AUTH} http://127.0.0.1:9200/ failed with RC ${RC}"
    exit ${RC}
  fi
  # ready if HTTP code 200, 503 is tolerable if ES version is 6.x
  if [[ ${HTTP_CODE} == "200" ]]; then
    exit 0
  elif [[ ${HTTP_CODE} == "503" && "7" == "6" ]]; then
    exit 0
  else
    echo "curl --output /dev/null -k -XGET -s -w '%{http_code}' \${BASIC_AUTH} http://127.0.0.1:9200/ failed with HTTP code ${HTTP_CODE}"
    exit 1
  fi

else
  echo 'Waiting for elasticsearch cluster to become ready (request params: "wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s" )'
  if http "/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s" "--fail" ; then
    touch ${START_FILE}
    exit 0
  else
    echo 'Cluster is not yet ready (request params: "wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s" )'
    exit 1
  fi
fi
] delay=10s timeout=5s period=10s #success=3 #failure=3
    Environment Variables from:
      es-creds   Secret     Optional: false
      es-ilm-cm  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:
      cluster.name:                                          es
      node.name:                                             elasticsearch-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD:                                      <set to the key 'ES_PASS' in secret 'es-creds'>  Optional: false
      ingest.geoip.downloader.enabled:                       false
      network.host:                                          0.0.0.0
      cluster.initial_master_nodes:                          elasticsearch-0,elasticsearch-1,
      discovery.seed_hosts:                                  elasticsearch-headless
      cluster.deprecation_indexing.enabled:                  false
      path.data:                                             /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/data
      path.logs:                                             /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/logs
      ES_JAVA_OPTS:                                          -Xms2g -Xmx2g
      xpack.security.enabled:                                true
      xpack.security.authc.realms.native.native1.order:      0
      xpack.security.authc.realms.file.file1.order:          1
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled:                  true
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode:        certificate
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.key:                      /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.key
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate:              /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/tls.crt
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities:  /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca.crt
    Mounts:
      /tmp/elastic/ from es-ilm (rw)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs from es-certs (ro)
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/data from es-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-rrwh9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  es-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  es-storage-elasticsearch-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  es-ilm:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      es-ilm
    Optional:  false
  es-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  es-certs
    Optional:    false
  kube-api-access-rrwh9:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

Everything else seems fine: PVC,PV,CM,Secrets etc.., also this works on k8s 1.23 and below, and on AKS too i believe.

Tried lots of things, sometimes i managed to get it running after force deleting it but it will complain about another instance running on the machine after that.

Comment: Most likely guess is that the instance with room for the pod isn't in the right availability zone for the persistent volume. Check events on the nodes and general events.

Comment: Have you installed the EBS CSI driver?

Comment: Hey, @jordanm about the zone they are both on the same node Thanks!

Comment: And yes @jeremy-cowan the EBS CSI is up and updated, also all other PV are fine and their pods are running, so i believe the issue is somewhere else, Thanks!

Comment: Might want to look at the scheduler logs then.

Comment: @jeremy-cowan they seem fine, the pod is bound: `Successfully bound pod to node pod="XXXXXXX/elasticsearch-1" node="XXXXXXXX" evaluatedNodes=1 feasibleNodes=1`

Comment: Also, after force killing the pods without deleting the PVC it does start and fails with this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/data]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?`